# Homomorphism of groups, subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

If $f: G_1\to G_2$ is homomorphism of groups $G_1$ and $G_2$ and if $|G_2|=25$ and $A$ is subgroup of $G_1$ such that $A\neq \{e\}$, and $f(A)\neq G_2$, prove that $f(A)$ is a subgroup of $G_2$, and find the order of $G_2$.

Comment: What are your thoughts and what have you tried?  This comes across as though you're asking the site to do your homework for you, and that tends to attract downvotes.

Comment: The order of f(A) is probably 5. f(A) is subgroup of G2, the order of G2 is 25. 1, 5 and 25 are numbers that divide 25. According to Lagrange's theorem, subgroup order divides group order and since A is diffrent from G2 and from {e} so the orfer of f(A) can't be 1 and 25 so the order of f(A) is 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $f$ is a homomorphism, $f(e_{G_1})=e_{G_2}$. So, $e_{G_2}\in f(A)$ and also, $f(A)$ is not empty.

Also, you can show that for a homomorphism, $f(g^{-1})=f(g)^{-1}$. This means that $f(gh^{-1})=f(g)f(h^{-1})=f(g)f(h)^{-1}$. So, for all $f(g),f(h) \in f(A)$, we have that $f(g)f(h)^{-1} \in f(A)$. This, together with the fact that $f(A)$ contains the identity, proves that $f(A)$ is a subgroup of $G_2$.

Now that we know it's a subgroup, by Lagrange's theorem, we know that $o(f(A)) \mid o(G_2)=25$. Since $f(A) \neq \{e\}$, we should have that $o(f(A))=5 \text{ or } 25$. Since $f(A) \neq G_2$, it can't be $25$ and therefore $o(f(A))=5$.